# Deploy multiple projects using PostSharp on a target machine without the PostSharp MSI

Tags: c#, postsharp

We have several projects hanging off of a solution, a website and some services. Each will utilise PostSharp but as we do not want to install PostSharp on the target machine using the MSI we can deploy the relevant suite of PostSharp dependencies as detailed in this blogpost by Scott Wojan.

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20200808070452/http://geekswithblogs.net/wojan/archive/2009/01/14/128673.aspx)

This example is fine for a single project.

The question is, how to go about only deploying one set of dependencies to the target machine and have each project reference them from different directories?

Answer (score 0):

A common solution is to copy PostSharp to your source repository. In this case, you don't have to 'deploy' it on target machines, you just need to check it out from source code.

In this case, projects using PostSharp should reference PostSharp.targets using a relative path.